# Download files in iPhone application?

Tags: iphone, download, file-transfer

1) How to initialize a download of contents, say a document or XML, to iPhone?

2) Where will the downloaded files be stored?

3) Any restrictions on file download? Any forbidden files?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Take a look at ASIHttpRequest. Works prefect for downloading files.
http://allseeing-i.com/ASIHTTPRequest/

Regards, Paul

Comment: This library is useful, but it mentions it supports only up to iPhone 2.1 API... I am developing iPhone Apps at version 3.1.2

Comment: I use it for my 3.0 > apps and works perfect. I use it in Stationen, Stationen Plus & Stockholm City Bikes.