# Download a file to iPhone

Tags: iphone, objective-c, save, uitextview

Hy Everybody,

I hope enyone cann explain me how I can save an file on the iPhone

I get the file with NSURL so fare no prob.
I'd like to donload the file and work with the donloaded file.
But I have no Idea how.

Comment: possible duplicate of [Download files in iPhone application?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1872302/download-files-in-iphone-application)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Check this for downloading: [Apple docs](http://developer.apple.com/iphone/library/documentation/Cocoa/Conceptual/URLLoadingSystem/Tasks/UsingNSURLConnection.html)

After downloading the file, you will probably have the contents of the file on a NSMutableData.

Check the documentation on NSData, you have a method [writeToFile:](http://developer.apple.com/iphone/library/documentation/Cocoa/Reference/Foundation/Classes/NSData_Class/Reference/Reference.html#//apple_ref/occ/instm/NSData/writeToFile:options:error:)

Comment: that pretty much worked but the written file is empty.
I tried NSKeyedArchiver now the file isn't empty anymore but it just contains signs?
What's my fault?!?

Comment: Ahh sorry my fault I saved the file at the request not when it's Downloaded.

but I still got this at the top of the document:
<  
bplist00ÔT$topX$objectsX$versionY$archiverÑTroot€£ 
U$nullÒ
WNS.dataV$classO(G   >

what's that anyway and how can I get rid of it
and why does it creates a snapshop too?!?

Answer (score 0):

Create NSData with contentsOfURL
Now use this data to write in a file. You can create file in the NSHomeDirecotry() using NSFileManager.